# Trying to close one modal and open another but both keep closing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using angular 4, bootstrap 4 (beta), and ngx-bootstrap. I am trying to create a modal service that will serve as an alert dialog on any page. The problem is that I am trying to close the `test` modal and open the `alert` modal but the `alertModal` doesnt open I'm guessing because `this.bsModalRef.hide` is hiding both of them.

What am I doing wrong?

test.html

```
<div bsModal #newBidModal="bs-modal"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog w-100">
        <div class="modal-content w-100">
            <form class="form-group" [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(testForm.value)">
            </form
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<app-modal  #childModal [title]="'Modal'">
  <div class="modal-body">
    {{message}}
  </div>
</app-modal>
```

test.component.ts

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  TestComponent: any;

  @ViewChild('childModal') childModal: ModalComponent;
  message: string;

  constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef){}

  onSubmit(input:any) {
    this.API.post(input).subscribe(data => {
      this.bsModalRef.hide();
      this.alert();
    });
  }
}

alert() {
    this.childModal.title = 'hi';
    this.message = 'test';
    this.childModal.show();
}
```

alert-modal.html

```
<div bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{title}}</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" (click)="childModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ng-content select=".modal-body"> </ng-content>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="childModal.hide()"> Cancel </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

alert-modal.ts

```
export class AlertModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('childModal') public childModal: ModalDirective;

  @Input() title: string;
  constructor() {
  }
  show() {
    this.childModal.show();
  }
  hide() {
    this.childModal.hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you create a plunkr with reproduction of this issue? Starter templates - Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/0NipkZrnckZZROAcnjzB?p=preview

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-stack?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

I have not work on angular js or use "ngx-bootstrap" but if what you want to achieve is "close one modal and open another" you can do that in  bootstrap by adding `data-toggle` and `data-target` to the buttons of the first modal to open the next modal on closing.

Say you have a modal button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
      Launch First Modal
</button>
```

Which targets this modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <!-- rest of modal content here, closing button targets exampleModal2 -->
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second Modal here, with id `exampleModal2`  would be opened if the first one is closed.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
  <!-- Modal content -->
</div>
```

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/akassama/gzq6thuk/)

Comment: can you do this via an anchor link for a modal to open another modal? I dont want to open another just by closing another modal. I want to select a link from within the first modal to open the second modal, and thus closing the first modal.

Comment: @Krys Yes you can, just add the data-dismiss and data-target attributes to the link like this:  `<a data-dismiss="modal"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#secondModal">Link</a> `